# Removing/ hiding Mongo ObjectID from the KeystoneJS URL

Tags: mongodb, url, hash, keystonejs, keystone

Is there any way to remove or hide the mongo Object ID from the URLs generated by the Keystone.js website.

Example:

When I try to go to any product posted using the CMS admin from the website I can see the exact same MongoID (_id) of that document attached with the URL:

http://abc.def/xyz/58a6d7eb177b563c595683ba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses.

I have solved this issue by giving the unique "key" relation in the keytone.js and used the same "key" as navigation in URLs.
By doing that, we just had to change the relationship of objectIDs to keys and everything started working fine without the objectIDs in the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Within the Admin UI there isn't a way of hiding the Mongo DB item document. That's how the Admin UI knows what document it's looking at. You can create your own administrative interface that is disjoint from the one that comes with Keystone, then implement your own method for URL based document viewing (by the item's name, key, or some other meaningful information).

Comment: Thank you for kind information. But creating a different UI would not help.
That's the reason we choose CMS. Now creating some different UI is not a question.

Need the method to hide or remove the Mongo ID.

Comment: To clear the thoughts,
I would like you to know that: this question is not for ADMIN UI.
It is for the website, that actual user will interface with.

Comment: So this isn't for Keystone's administrative interface (accessed from `/keystone/`), but some other Admin UI that you already have?